# Ошибка при импорте cv2 python : undefined symbol

Tags: python, opencv, raspbian

При импорте выдаёт такую ошибкук

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vanya/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/home/vanya/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: /home/vanya/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_store_8
```